# Dynamically allocate string to contain user input in C

Tags: c, input, malloc, user-input, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
  char* a;
  scanf("%s",a);
  printf("%s", a);
  free(a);
  return 0;
}
```

My question is dynamic allocation without static declaration.

I want to do dynamic assignment with just in the input statement.
Internal code or Not by a static declaration...
However, dynamic allocation is not possible with the above input this code.
Is there any other way?
By not touching the inner code or making static declarations.

Comment: I have understood nothing.:)

Comment: Mee too. But you can't `free` something that was never allocated, as the code presented does. Well, scanning into it and printing it is invalid too.

Comment: I guess OP is looking for something like the CS50 [`get_string()`](https://manual.cs50.io/3/get_string)

Comment: Are you trying to allocate exactly enough characters for the input to fit inside the string?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`realloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm) from `<stdlib.h>` to achieve it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    fputs("Input: ", stdout);
    char *str = malloc(1);

    int c, i;
    for (i = 0; (c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF; ++i) {
        str[i] = c;
        str = realloc(str, i + 2);
    }
    str[i] = '\0';

    printf("Output: %s\n", str);
    free(str);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But I would not advise you to do that, because it can be expensive depending on the implementation. Instead I would just create a string with fixed size and prevent a buffer overflow.

```
char str[20];
scanf("%19s", str);
```

Or using `fgets`:

```
char str[20];
fgets(str, 20, stdin);
```

Comment: thank you for the good answer. AND...  I'm learning English, so the writing is weird. :(